# How to get percentage of rows from database by a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I have a table where processes are distincted by their kind. But sometimes a lot of processes of the same kind are inserted in sequence, for example:

```
PROCESSID | KIND
1         |  1
2         |  1
3         |  1
4         |  1
5         |  2
6         |  3
```

Nowadays my query get the rows ordered by ID, but imagine in the example above, a situation when there is thousands of the same kind "1" in sequence, it's a problem for me.

I would like to get the rows by percentage, for example: Take 500 rows where 10% is kind "1", 20% is kind "2", and 50% is kind "3".

My desired result is the PROCESSIDs and not the percentage of kinds in database.

How could I do this to SQL Server and Oracle?

Comment: Do you want to _know_ the percentage (so Gordon's answer may work) or do you want a result with the _expected percentages_? The latter seems very difficult, and what would the missing 20% be?

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: @RenéVogt I want to take the results based on the percentage. I want 500 rows, 10% of kind "1" (50), 20% kind "2" (100) etc...  This is just an example there are more kinds and percentages.

Comment: And, for example, is there isn't kind "1" in database, I want to continue retrieving 500 rows, but of another kinds dinamically. Did you understand?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in SQL Server and Oracle using window/analytic functions:

```
select kind, count(*) as numvals,
       count(*) * 1.0 / sum(count(*)) over () as proportion
from t
group by kind;
```

Comment: My desired result is the PROCESSIDs and not the percentage of kinds in database.

Comment: @OnlyaCuriousMind  . . . I don't understand.  You should edit the question and include desired results.